# How can I get sum of items that do not belong to a set in google or-tools

Tags: constraints, or-tools

I am trying to implement equations containing these.

[Sum not belongs to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16BFX.png)

These items are Boolean variable. So, if it is part of the solution it will set to 1 else it will be 0 after calling the solve method.

If it was the opposite (belongs to) then I would simple loop over all the items and after solving it, I would check if the variable is set to 1 or not.

I am using MIP solver with SCIP backend (C++)

```
std::unique_ptr<MPSolver> solver(MPSolver::CreateSolver("SCIP"));

std::vector<const MPVariable *> z(edges.size());

 for (int e = 0; e < edges.size(); e++)
    {
        z[e] = solver->MakeBoolVar(absl::StrFormat("z_%d, %d", edges.at(e).at(0), edges.at(e).at(1)));
    }
```

Here, z is Boolean variable

The way I get the sum

```
LinearExpr sum_z;
for (int e = 0; e < z.size(); e++)
{
    sum_z += LinearExpr(z[e]);
}
```

I really cannot think of any way for this. Tried to search for "or-tools not belongs to set sum" in the google. No luck. Tried to find these in the examples of or-tools. Still no idea.

If you can give any hint or idea. Please share

Edit:
Attempt to subtract sum of z_e from size of z (equal to edges)

```
(LinearExpr(z.size()) - sum_z)
```

to check whether the value is true or not

```
for (int e = 0; e < z.size(); e++)
{
       if (z[e]->solution_value() > 0)
       {
            // true
        }
 }
```

The expression is used to define constraints like this
[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8JRC.png)

Here, E and V both are set of Boolean Variable. The complication in my situation is summing the elements not inside a set.

Comment: Could you please provide more details (some code?) about how to determine which variables "are part of the solution"? You have a set of `Z_e` 's; are these the Booleans?  How is the set `E` represented? Is `e` simply an integer, or also a variable?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins Added some code for declaring and initializing Z. They are Boolean variables. Thanks for your time.

Comment: And how do you determine which values of e "are part of the solution"?

Comment: Basically there are bunch of constraints. You set them and call the solve() method on that solver pointer. Then these Booleans are set to either 0 or 1 depending whether they are part of optimal solution or not. I wish I could give the whole code and all the constraints. But I can't

Comment: I must be missing something. The sum of `Z_e` where `Z_e` is 0 is of course also 0. So what is it that determines which `Z_e` to sum, or do you want the sum of the `e` s?

Comment: If you want to determine the *number* of items that are not in the set, you can simply sum up all the `Z_e` 's and subtract the sum from `edges.size()`.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins that seems a nice idea. I will try that one.

About your previous comment, "So what is it that determines which Z_e to sum, or do you want the sum of the e s?". I also dont know much about the inner workings of or-tools. All I know,

I define variables, define a set of constrains, then when I call the solve() method the value is set based on the found solution.

The way I get the sum is added in the post

Comment: So it seems you are trying to *count* how many `z` are zero, not "sum them up"? Yes, then you can simply subtract your `sum_z` from `edges.size()`.

Comment: "subtract the sum from edges.size()" did not work unfortunately

Comment: Could you add the code you used to compute that difference and how you access its value in the solution?

Comment: My process is very similar to or-tools example of multiple knapsack

https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/multiple_knapsack

I am adding the difference and accessing value part

Comment: What exactly is not working with `(LinearExpr(z.size()) - sum_z)`  ? (I assume you meant `sum_z` not `sum_z_e` as I don't see the latter defined anywhere. Do you need the value in the model, or only afterwards in the solution?

Comment: Basically I have a solution (result from the program) from one implementation. Now, I have to implement it a bit differently. So, the result would be same. But previous one did not use "not belongs to set" type of notation. And that is where the problem is.

" (I assume you meant sum_z not sum_z_e" => yes that's a typo.

The latest this i tried is like this - LinearExpr(!z[e]), which is negating z[e]

Still my solution dont match.

And again thanks for your interest and time.

Comment: I still don't understand what is not working with `(LinearExpr(z.size()) - sum_z)`. Does it give you a syntax error? The wrong value? Some other problem? What do you do with that expression in your code? You can't use `!` operator with a BoolVar, you have to use `1-z[e]` or `LinearExpr::NotVar(z[e])`

Comment: "I still don't understand what is not working with ...", No sir, it is not giving any error. But it is not printing correct result.

"What do you do with that expression in your code?" => I am trying to define a constraint.

I have added a sample constraint at the end of the post for more information. 

" you have to use 1-z[e] or LinearExpr::NotVar(z[e])" => Thanks for this information. I did not know about it.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No one is going to be able to help unless you include the essential parts of your code. The key part of the question is "What do you do with that expression **in your code** ?". Also, as far as I can see, the information provided in the comments and edits show that you don't really want to implement the sum in the screenshot but instead want to count the number of z that are 0, which is something completely different.